# iOS is it bad to not use loadView at all?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, release

Xcode 4.3.3, ios 5.1, using ARC. Nearly done with my first app, had a few questions

1) I was wondering if it was bad style to not use storyboard and to not drag in my view objects. If i did everything in viewDidLoad, is that bad for any reasons?

2) Also, I finished my app and made no changes to The AppDelegate class... is that unusual? Is there some stuff I'm missing and should account for?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends.  Are you a hobbyist, just hacking?  Or are you a professional, and want to do it the right way, that scales towards working on large apps that are built by teams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need some functionality, then don't be afraid not implementing it. You don't have to always fill everything.

Also, it's essentially unimportant where you do your initialization. For example, I don't like loadView; I also initialize my custom view controllers in an `initWith...:` method.

Furthermore, don't be scared about not using a storyboard. Apple gives us these convenient development tools to make development easier, but it's not obligatory to use them, nor it is bad practice not to use them. Personally, I don't use IB at all.

Answer (score 2):

1. It is a common practice to initialise and allocate objects in
   `viewDidLoad`,unless you want them to be allocated again..in that case
   you should use them in `viewWillAppear`. Storyboard is an optional
   choice.Making your first project without a storyboard is perfectly
   ok.
2. Making any change to your AppDelegate is your choice,like you want
   to use a tabBar or any SplitView or you want to add any additional
   navigationController.

so both of the things you did are ok.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a good reason to use viewDidLoad, even if you're not loading from NIB.

A good implementation of viewDidLoad and viewDidUnload can allow didReceiveMemoryWarning to release views that are not currently displayed, potentially saving your app from being killed.

I started writing this reply thinking that they are released automatically, but I think that is something I mis-remembered.